# ReactJS RSuite 3 not rendering the components properly

Tags: reactjs, button, styling

I created a new react app by using `npx create-react-app test`, then I installed rsuite by using `npm install rsuite` and imported `Button` and `ButtonGroup` and the `index.less` file:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'rsuite';

// import default style
import 'rsuite/styles/less/index.less'; // or 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite.min.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Button>
          Hey
        </Button>
        <Button>
          asd
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But the buttons are not styled and instead are shown like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Link to the documentation: https://rsuitejs.com/en/guide/usage

Answer (score 11):

Although a little late,

But I found a solution by replacing

```
    import 'rsuite/styles/less/index.less';
```

to

```
    import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css';
```

Comment: Precise answer Harshul Yadav.

Answer (score 5):

rsuite 5.6.1

```js
import 'rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css';
```

Comment: Best and Most Current answer

Answer (score 3):

To use it with react-create-app the CSS to import is different:

replace

```
import 'rsuite/styles/less/index.less';
```

with

```
import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite.min.css';
```